# How can I access a local HTML file on Windows 8 Phone?

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, local

I have been following this guide on displaying website pages as an app (http://antonylees.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html).

Everything works apart from trying to access a local HTML file as a fallback option when there is no internet connection. I have researched and tried multiple methods to try and do this without luck. The 'This app requires an internet connection' popup works fine, but when trying to load the local HTML file, I either get a grey screen or the 'Page cannot be found' message.

The suggested way is:

```
window.location="local/index.html";
```

I have also tried:

```
window.location.href ="local/index.html";
```

and:

```
window.open('local/index.html');
```

The 'local' folder is a sub-folder of 'www'.

Is there something specific to Windows Phone 8 that I am missing? Any other ideas?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express, The latest version of Cordova, and live debugging on a Nokia Lumia 820.

Comment: When I was making a local offline copy of a site for my Windows-Phone app, I had to copy all website content to Isolated storage and then load it from there to WebBrowser object. That worked fine. The link, you've provided has very broad explanation of what to do, you should be more specific about how you tried to do this on Windows Phone platform.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was completely unrelated to Cordova etc.

I am new to MS Visual Studio and this was my first project using it. I noticed that the local HTML file I was trying to load was not showing in the Solution Explorer. I realised that I had created the file externally of MSVS. As a result I had to right click in the solution  explorer and add an existing item. Once I had done that everything worked fine using the same code as in the tutorial. I am guessing that the compile process only includes files listed in the solution explorer.

Thanks for looking anyway! And at least I now know how to display code correctly in Stack Overflow ;)